# Flutter if statement not functioning

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This should be an easy one but I've been stuck for hours.

Situation: I'm trying to execute the `signOutProcess` to log out of Firebase if the user is not authorized. I've set up a field in Firestore, 1 for authorized and 0 for not authorized. It prints the correct result, I can get it to sign out if I remove the `if` statement but that defeats the purpose.

Question: How do I get the `if` statement to execute `signOutProcess` when the nested value is retrieved?

```dart
  void getUserAuthorization  () {
    String uid = firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid;
    print('this is uid $uid');
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users2022')
        .doc(uid)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) async {
      dynamic nested = documentSnapshot.get(FieldPath(['Authorized']));
        print('this is the authorization condition $nested');
        if (nested == 0) {
          signOutProcess();
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding await keyword while assigning nested?

Comment: As in dynamic nested = await documentSnapshot ? It doesn't change anything. I can still print as it's getting the value. Perhaps I misunderstand where the await goes. I've tried making the whole thing async with await, still doesn't seem to fix it. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Add a print statement inside if statement and see whether it's running, also is there no error showing up, errors from api response or anything like that?

Comment: I'm with @CherryDT here: if you see a `0` being printed, but it doesn't go into that `if`, most likely the value is not a number in the database.

Comment: Yes yes that's it, I tried changing the types of both of values to int or string earlier, I was on the right track just had no idea what I was doing, thank you @CherryDT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the value you get is `'0'` and not `0`, i.e. it's a *string*!

It won't be equal to the number `0` then, and instead you'd have to write `if (nested == '0')`.

You can try `print(nested.runtimeType)` to see what you actually got there.